# How to Factory reset ESP8266?

Tags: arduino-mega, esp8266, wifi, reset

I want to use ESP8266 to send emails. I tried twice flashing the Firmware to a particular firmware as suggested in a tutorial. Now both my ESP are unresponsive to AT commands. Let me know the way to RESET it. CH_PD + VCC + RST (Tried this combination), No success there any thing i am missing?

Comment: Flash the correct firmware.

Comment: You are missing that this is the Arduino SE.  You might get better answers on the EE SE which covers ESP8266

Answer (score 2):

AT commands are executed by the AT interpreter firmware. If you've been attempting to flash other firmware to the ESP8266 module, there is no longer any code in it that interprets AT commands. If you want to it to respond to AT commands again, you'll need to re-flash it with that firmware.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reflash the "AT Firmware" you probably overwrited.
Just follow the [instructions in the Espressif board](http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=433) to get the latest one using their "Flash Download Tool".